# Understanding conditional page background in ConTeXt

Tags: backgrounds, context-mkiv

How does the following code work? Source: [discussion on the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg68592.html)

```
\setuplayout
  [header=0cm,
   topspace=1.625cm,
   footer=0cm,
   width=fit,
   height=fit]

\startMPinclusions
  numeric MyTitlePageDone[] ;
\stopMPinclusions

\startuseMPgraphic{background:normal}
  StartPage ;
  fill
    (topboundary Page --cycle) enlarged(0,5mm) shifted (0,-5mm)
    withcolor \MPcolor{color:background:\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor}} ;
  StopPage ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [background:normal]
  [\useMPgraphic{background:normal}]

\startuseMPgraphic{background:title}
  if unknown MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} :
    StartPage ;
    fill ((topboundary Page --cycle) enlarged(0,5mm))
      shifted (0,-20mm)
      withcolor \MPcolor{color:title:\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor}} ;
    StopPage ;
    MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} := 1 ;
  fi ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [background:title]
  [\useMPgraphic{background:title}]

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background={background:normal,background:title}]

\definecolor [color:title:one]      [r=0.86,g=0.88,b=0.76]
\definecolor [color:background:one] [.9(color:title:one)]

\definecolor [color:title:two]      [g=0.86,r=0.88,b=0.76]
\definecolor [color:background:two] [.9(color:title:two)]

\starttext

\startchapter[title=One][mycolor=one]
  \input tufte \page
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Two][mycolor=two]
  \input tufte \page
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Why are the backgrounds being applied conditionally? Why isn't the title page background applied to normal pages? In the code there doesn't seem to be any conditionals or checks to check the page type. The title background also gets applied to cover pages implemented via \startstandardmakeup, but gets a black color instead since the user variable isn't defined.

Some help in understanding this code is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's walk through the code. I skip the parts that are not relevant for
understanding the conditional processing. First an empty MetaPost array is
created.

```
\startMPinclusions
  numeric MyTitlePageDone[] ;
\stopMPinclusions
```

Now comes the part that actually prints the colourful bar underneath the
chapter head.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{background:title}
  if unknown MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} :
    StartPage ;
    fill ((topboundary Page --cycle) enlarged(0,5mm))
      shifted (0,-20mm)
      withcolor \MPcolor{color:title:\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor}} ;
    StopPage ;
    MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} := 1 ;
  fi ;
\stopuseMPgraphic
```

Let's simplify this code a little more:

```
\startuseMPgraphic{background:title}
  if unknown MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} :
    %%
    %% code for printing colourful bar skipped
    %%
    MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} := 1 ;
  fi ;
\stopuseMPgraphic
```

The macro `\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor}` expands to the
argument of the variable `mycolor` of the second argument provided to the `\startchapter`
command, which is `one` in this case:

```
\startchapter[title=One][mycolor=one]
```

This means the line

```
if unknown MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} :
```

eventually becomes

```
if unknown MyTitlePageDone.one ;
```

which is a way to address the array element *one* in MetaPost. At each new
chapter this condition evaluates to `true` since `MyTitlePageDone[one]` is
indeed unknown. It has never been set before. The following code draws the
colourful bar until this code is reached:

```
MyTitlePageDone.\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{mycolor} := 1 ;
```

which becomes

```
MyTitlePageDone.one := 1 ;
```

and thus defines this array element. The number is not relevant since it's
checked for `unknown`, not a particular value. On the next page the
conditional

```
if unknown MyTitlePageDone.one ;
```

evaluates to `false` since this value is known (it was set to one on the previous page) and the code printing the bar is skipped.

This code relies on the fact that every chapter has a unique colour. Try what
happens if you select the same colour for different chapters (use the
`mycolor=` setting) and walk through the code again to find out why.