# ConTeXt: Set margin background colour for all chapter pages

Tags: color, margins, context, chapters, backgrounds

## Problem

The `\setupbackgrounds` macro has the ability to change the background colour of the margins, from the top of the page to the bottom:

```
  \setupbackgrounds[footer,header,text][rightmargin][
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=blue,
  ]
```

However, once set, there does not seem to be a way to stop the backgrounds. This is preventing me from setting the background colour for only the chapter pages.

I'm fairly certain I could use a layer for this, but since `\setupbackgrounds` already has context for the right margin's header, footer, and text areas, I thought it would be easiest to commandeer this macro:

```
  \setuphead[chapter][
    header=empty,
    footer=empty,
    before={%
      \setupbackgrounds[footer,header,text][rightmargin][
        background=color,
        backgroundcolor=blue,
        state=repeat,
      ]
    },
    after={%
      \setupbackgrounds[footer,header,text][rightmargin][
        background=color,
        backgroundcolor=blue,
        state=stop,
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The `state=stop` doesn't stop the margin from being blue after the chapter page. Rather, the blue continues in the margin for the remainder of the document. I tried to stop the blue within the section:

```
  \setuphead[section][
    before={%
      \setupbackgrounds[][][state=stop]
    }
  ]
```

## Question

Is it possible to use a `\setupbackground` in this way (if so, how)?

If not, how would you use a layer to fill in the right-hand margin from the top of the page to the bottom?

## Related

- http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2009/039667.html
- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Overlays
- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles#Title_page_with_special_background

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to use Metapost backgrounds and use the trick described in [Conditional page backgrounds in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109282/323).

```
\startMPinclusions
  numeric ChapterPageDone[];
\stopMPinclusions

\startuseMPgraphic{chapterbackground}
  StartPage;
  n := \somenamedheadnumber{chapter}{current};

  x0 := PaperWidth - BackSpace;
  x1 := x0 + RightMarginWidth;

  if n > 0 : % ignore pages before the first chapter
    if unknown ChapterPageDone[n] : % This is the first page a new chapter
          fill (x0,0) -- (x1,0) -- (x1, PaperHeight) -- (x0, PaperHeight) -- cycle
               withcolor \MPcolor{blue};
        ChapterPageDone[n] := 1 ;
    fi;
  fi;
  StopPage;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[chapterbackground][\useMPgraphic{chapterbackground}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=chapterbackground]

\setuppapersize[A6]

\starttext

Non chapter page

\chapter{First}
Chapter page
\page

Non chapter page

\chapter{Second}
Chapter page

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

**EDIT** Based on the comment below, the above method will not work for unnumbered section heads. In that case, one option is to check if there has been a change in the title of chapter. Such an approach will work as long as you do not have two chapters with identical titles.

```
\startMPinclusions
  string prevChapterTitle, currentChapterTitle;
  prevChapterTitle := "";
  currentChapterTitle := "";
\stopMPinclusions

\startuseMPgraphic{chapterbackground}
  StartPage;
  currentChapterTitle := "\namedstructurevariable{chapter}{title}";

  x0 := PaperWidth - BackSpace;
  x1 := x0 + RightMarginWidth;

  if currentChapterTitle <> prevChapterTitle :
        fill (x0,0) -- (x1,0) -- (x1, PaperHeight) -- (x0, PaperHeight) -- cycle
             withcolor \MPcolor{blue};
     prevChapterTitle := currentChapterTitle ;
  fi;
  StopPage;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[chapterbackground][\useMPgraphic{chapterbackground}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=chapterbackground]
```

To exclude the table of contents page, make the following minor change:

```
if prevChapterText <> "":
  fill (x0,0) -- (x1,0) -- (x1, PaperHeight) -- (x0, PaperHeight) -- cycle
    withcolor \MPcolor{blue};
fi;
```

Comment: Yes, this relies on the value of section number, so it will not work with `number=no`. Let me think of an alternative for unnumbered section heads. BTW, instead of using `beforesection=\page`, you should use `page=yes`.

Comment: To separate chapter and section use `continue=no`. You can use chapter title as well. I'll need to look up the internal command for that.